# why this code run if? android

Tags: android

When tempPackageName_pInfo = "aaaa.asaddsdaa" 
"aaaa.asaddsdaa" is package name that non exist on android market.
why code is run in "if". It should be run "else"

```
for (PackageInfo pInfo : appinstalled) {
        String tempPackageName_pInfo = pInfo.packageName.toString();
        appinstalledTest = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                + tempPackageName_pInfo));
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);// 0
    if (list.size() > 0) { runIf(); } else { runElse(); }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what `list` contains?

Comment: I think "list" must be empty(size == 0) because package "aaaa.asaddsdaa" non exist on android market. (I used this [url](https://market.android.com/search?q=aaaa.asaddsdaa) for search so then market://details?id=aaaa.asaddsdaa non exist on android market too.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, you need to use a debugger to actually see what `list` is, not what you think it should be.  Often times we won't realize the small mistakes me make until we use a debugger to step through the program and inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs for `queryIntentActivities`

> Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.

As far as I understand this means that there is at least the Market activity, which can be preformed for this intent. This method can not rely on either this particular package exists in the Market or not.

Comment: Yes, I think this method can reply package exists in the Market or not. 
(Although there are some "Package" duplicate. I don't care in this case.)
You have other method to check "package name" exists in the market or not?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Indyway to check if an application exists in the market or not is totally different question. there is no way to do it using any official api as far as I know. but you could try google some unofficial alternatives like http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ (please note that I havent tried this api myself)

Comment: I used to try it for this [api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) i don't know to used it. I used to read document, I don't understand
I give for example,Help me please.

Comment: @Indyway Unfortunately I have to experience with this api and not able to help you with that. All I can recommend is to follow this example http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps and its discussion thread